# Deserialize XML with xmls:xsd and xmlns:xsi

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I need to deserialize XML file to an object in C#:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Test xmlns:xsd=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>
<Number>110658419900</Number>
<WorkorderName>2103477915XVN35S_FR_LEFTX111</WorkorderName>
<RequestDate>2022-10-13T16:53:13.2171314+02:00</RequestDate> 
<ShelfNumber>4</ShelfNumber> 
</Test>


public class Test
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string WorkorderName { get; set; }
    public string RequestDate { get; set; }
    public string ShelfNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this approach:

```
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileSystemEventArgs.FullPath);
            Test test = (Test)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            return test;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
        }
```

But I am receiving an error:

```
{"There is an error in XML document (2, 17)."}
```

Everything is working If I remove this from XML:
xmlns:xsd=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

I don't know why this is happening. How to solve this issue? How to ignore this xmls:xsd and xmls:xsi?

Comment: Shouldn't the value of attribute should be wrap with quotes?

Comment: You are missing four double quotes around the two URL in the namespace on 2nd line.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks. I did not notice it, because I am not creating this XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "xml" **isn't valid xml**, and the parser is correct to shout here. The xml should start (note the quotes):

```xml
<Test xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

(etc)

However, those are just namespace alias declarations, and those aliases *are never used*, so: you can also just delete them here, leaving your xml as starting

```xml
<Test>
```

Comment: Problem is that I am receiving this XML from a different provider. But thank you for pointing out that there is an issue with formatting. I did not notice it.

Comment: @KacperSierakowski no, you are receiving this *corrupt non-xml thing* from a different provider; this is entirely a conversation for them, and they need to fix this problem. It should be a very quick conversation: "hey, that API that you said returns xml? well, it isn't returning xml; can you fix that ta? kthxbye"